# Detecting the position of the blob in a small image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect and get y-coordinate of the blob on a small portion of camera feed.
Processed image looks like this [rROImask:black square fills it edge to edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuuIH.png)

As of now, i am stuck at getting `SimpleBlobDetector()` to work, no matter the parameters i choose.
detector call and keypoint drawing looks like this

```
keypointsR = det.detect(rROImask)
highlightR = cv2.drawKeypoints(rROImask, keypointsR,np.array([]),(255,0,0), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS))
```

Can you please suggest some solution?

Comment: try color thresholding using cv2.inRange(). Then get the contour of the white region.

Comment: i already used cv2.inRange() to create a mask. How exactly am i to get the contour? How would it help?

Comment: Once you have the contour, you can get the bounding box and thus the   y coord of the top or bottom or center. Search Google or this forum for examples using cv2.findContour(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0 and https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html